# New Azure DevOps pipeline using ASP.NET yaml template failing

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, .net-core-3.0

I have a GitHub repository with a .NET Core 3.0 website solution in it. In Azure DevOps, I went through the wizard to create a new pipeline linked to that repository using the **ASP.NET Core** template on the Configure step of the wizard. This is what my YAML looks like:

```
# ASP.NET Core
# Build and test ASP.NET Core projects targeting .NET Core.
# Add steps that run tests, create a NuGet package, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/dotnet-core

trigger:
- develop

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

When I try to manually run the pipeline to test it, this is the output I get everytime:

```
##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider NotFound
,##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider NotFound
,##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider NotFound
,##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider NotFound
,##[warning]There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider NotFound
,##[error]Provisioning request delayed or failed to send 5 time(s). This is over the limit of 3 time(s).
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: ubuntu-latest
Started: Yesterday at 10:04 PM
Duration: 10h 54m 5s

Job preparation parameters
ContinueOnError: False
TimeoutInMinutes: 60
CancelTimeoutInMinutes: 5
Expand:
  MaxConcurrency: 0
  ########## System Pipeline Decorator(s) ##########

  Begin evaluating template 'system-pre-steps.yml'
Evaluating: eq('true', variables['system.debugContext'])
Expanded: eq('true', Null)
Result: False
Evaluating: resources['repositories']['self']
Expanded: Object
Result: True
Evaluating: not(containsValue(job['steps']['*']['task']['id'], '6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4'))
Expanded: not(containsValue(Object, '6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4'))
Result: True
Evaluating: resources['repositories']['self']['checkoutOptions']
Result: Object
Finished evaluating template 'system-pre-steps.yml'
********************************************************************************
Template and static variable resolution complete. Final runtime YAML document:
steps:
- task: 6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4@1
  inputs:
    repository: self
```

I thought maybe **ubuntu-latest** was maybe no longer a valid vmImage, so I tried changing it to **ubuntu-18.04** and got the same result. The [Micosoft-hosted agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/hosted?view=azure-devops) documentation says either should be valid.

Do I have something wrong with my yaml file? I have setup pipelines before with the old no-yaml interface with no issues, so I am a little confused.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking through my account and noticed my Agent Pool settings looked a little suspect on the project. It showed I had 11 available agents that were online even though I was using the free plan on a private repository so it should only have one.

I ended up deleting my Azure DevOps organization and creating a new one. Now the YAML configuration I initially posted works fine.

Answer (score 0):

i think nowadays it should looks like this:

```
trigger:
- develop

jobs:
- job: buildjob
  variables:
    buildConfiguration: 'Release'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
    displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'
```

although [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pipeline) says you can omit jobs if you only have a single job, but I dont see anything wrong with your yaml other than the fact you use steps directly (which, again, should be fine)

Comment: Just gave this a try and it resulted in the same failure output for me.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like nothing wrong with your yaml file and format.

Since you are using a **GitHub repository** with a .NET Core 3.0 website. Please pay attention when you create pipeline, make sure you have selected GitHub not Azure Repos Git.

[image]

Also as you have mentioned `I have setup pipelines before with the old no-yaml interface with no issues`, you could setup your pipelines with classic editor first.

There is also a view yaml option.

[image]

You could follow that format and content to create a yaml template, which may do the trick.

Comment: `There was a failure in sending the provision message: Unexpected response code from remote provider NotFound` Besides, this kind of error may also related to network, kindly check this. Trigger it again.

Comment: Both creating it through the no-yaml screen and retrying the existing job gave me the same error. It looks like the issue was with my Agent Pool configuration, I posted more details in a separate comment.