# Why is test automation only partially successful with Cypress and Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, automated-tests, cypress

I am using Cypress.io (Version 5.1.0) for testing my project.
My project is in azure DevOps. Now i want to include my cypress tests in Azure DevOps so my tests will run automatically.

I set up the JUnit reporter on my Cypress project:
into my “package.json” file i added

```
"cypress-multi-reporters": "^1.2.4",
"mocha-junit-reporter": "^1.23.3"
```

then run
npm install

than added

```
  "scripts": {
  "scripts": "cypress run",
  "test": "npm run scripts"
}
```

Into my “cypress.json” file i added

```
    "reporter": "mocha-junit-reporter",
"reporterOptions": {
  "mochaFile": "cypress/reports/junit/test-results.[hash].xml",
  "testsuitesTitle": false
}
```

After this I created a new Pipeline using Azure Repos in Azure DevOps.
For Pipeline Configuration i selected Node.js.

Now I have a YAML file. Here i removed  `npm build` from the first script.

Now I picked npm from the assisstant. On the npm configurations, I selected `custom` and write the command `run test` . Now I Select the result format as “JUnit” and set Test results files to “*.xml”
At last I selected the option "Merge test results".
Now I saved and run the pipeline.

This is what my Job does:

```
Pool: Azure Pipelines
Image: ubuntu-latest
Agent: Hosted Agent
Started: Yesterday at 17:31
Expanded: Object
Result: True
Evaluating: not(containsValue(job['steps']['*']['task']['id'], '6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4'))
Expanded: not(containsValue(Object, '6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4'))
Result: True
Evaluating: resources['repositories']['self']['checkoutOptions']
Result: Object
Finished evaluating template 'system-pre-steps.yml'
********************************************************************************
Template and static variable resolution complete. Final runtime YAML document:
steps:
- task: 6d15af64-176c-496d-b583-fd2ae21d4df4@1
  inputs:
    repository: self


  MaxConcurrency: 0
```

What is wrong with my automation? How can I fix this?

Update:
Thats my yml file:

```
 # Node.js
# Build a general Node.js project with npm.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  inputs:
    versionSpec: '10.x'
  displayName: 'Install Node.js'

- script: |
    npm install
  displayName: 'npm install'

- task: Npm@1
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    customCommand: 'run test'
  continueOnError: true

- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'JUnit'
    testResultsFiles: '*.xml'
    searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/cypress/reports/junit'
    mergeTestResults: true
    testRunTitle: 'Publish Test Results'
```

I got an email with this Details

> Job 1 error(s), 1 warning(s)   Error: Npm failed with return code: 254

Comment: Please check if the answer below solves your issue. If not, could you edit your question and provide your yaml file? So that we can further investigate the issue.

Comment: this did not work for me. I changes ubuntu-latest to ubuntu-18.04

Comment: Please try to change the organization. I just found a relative [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937021/new-azure-devops-pipeline-using-asp-net-yaml-template-failing).

Comment: how to change the organization? in cypress or in azure? and if azure, should I add the project? because i want cypress tests to start automatically if there is any update at the project

Comment: In Azure DevOps, change to another organization and create a new project. Repeating all the configurations of the original project in the new project, just like moving the original project to the new organization.

Comment: `ubuntu-18.04` is another name for `ubuntu-latest`. Have you tried to use `ubuntu-20.04` or `ubuntu-16.04`?

Comment: i used 20.04 now and it does not change anything

Comment: I am sorry to hear that. Please refer to my comments on changing the organization

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be due to the agent rather than your code and scripts.

You can try the following solutions:

1. Change your agent image. As you are currently using the `ubuntu-latest`, it is recommanded to try the `ubuntu-20.04` or `ubuntu-16.04`.
2. Use a self-hosted agent. If you don't have a self-hosted agent, click [Self-hosted Linux agent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops) for detailed steps.
3. Change the orgnization. Choose another organization that can run the build correctly, and just in case, it is better to create a new organization. Then create a new project and try your tests.

Answer (score 0):

As stated already, the problem most likely lies with the Azure environment. Cypress has a dependency on a browser (electron, chrome) in order to execute. For example, if you are using docker, they provide an official image called [cypress/browsers:node14.7.0-chrome84](https://hub.docker.com/r/cypress/browsers/) that has everything you need out of the box. The [Dockerfile](https://hub.docker.com/r/cypress/browsers/dockerfile) also has useful info on the environment needed. Make sure to provide a headless configuration as well, something like:

```
cypress run --headless --browser chrome --spec yourSpecHere.js
```